# How to compare a map in groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

In a groovy script for Jenkins Pipeline, I have a map and few strings separated by comma. I want to compare each string with the keys of map and if the string is not present as key in map, then remove the entry from the map

Here is my code:

```
node=node1,node2

map=[
node1: [ name: "node1", property: "1234"],
node2: [ name: "node2", property: "2345"]
node3: [ name: "node3", property: "3456"]
]
```

Here only `node1` and `node2` are in node variable. So in my map, I need to only have `node1` and `node2`.

I tried something like this in my Jenkins DSL pipeline but it didn't work:

```
stages {
  stage('Build nodes') {
    steps {
      script{
        "${node}".tokenize( ',' ).each
        {n ->
            echo "Node Selected ${n}"
            new_map1=add_nodes("${n}")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
def new_map=[:]
def add_nodes(n){
     "${new_map}" << map."${node}"
     return "${new_map}"

}
```

**Error** I'm getting is:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: new_map for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def nodeArray = ['node1', 'node2']
def map=[
  node1: [ name: "node1", property: "1234"],
  node2: [ name: "node2", property: "2345"],
  node3: [ name: "node3", property: "3456"]
]
def map2=map.findAll{k,v-> v.name in nodeArray}
```